# How to limit memory usage for pdal to import LiDAR data

Tags: postgis, point-cloud, pdal, pgpointcloud

While trying to import LiDAR pointcloud data in .las format (my file is 38GB) to PostgreSQL using the pointcloud extension, I keep getting `Killed` after several minutes of the following command running (this is because memory runs out):

```
pdal pipeline pdal_pipeline_info.json
```

I also tried:

```
pdal pipeline --stdin < pdal_pipeline_info.json
```

Even with the `--developer-debug`, I get no other output whatsoever.

If I run the same command above via strace, once memory runs out, it outputs:

```
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
Killed
```

This is how my pdal_pipeline_info looks:

```
{
  "pipeline":[
    {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "filename":"/home/myuser/myfile.las",
      "spatialreference":"EPSG:4326"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.chipper",
      "capacity":600
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.pgpointcloud",
      "connection":"host='localhost' dbname='mydb' user='myuser' password='mypass'",
      "schema":"public",
      "table":"patches",
      "column":"pa",
      "compression":"dimensional",
      "srid":"4326"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there something I can do to not have pdal take up all system memory (48GB in my case)?

My `pdal --version` is `pdal 2.2.0 (git-version: Release)`

Comment: 1. Do you *really* want it in PostgreSQL? If so, those are super tiny chips, and making those is going to take tons of memory. Make bigger chips.

2. If you were to translate the file to something like COPC, you could incrementally read the data with PDAL or Python.

3. PDAL 2.2.0 is more than two years old. Nothing has changed in regard to PG or filters.chipper since that was released, however.